# MySQL как бороться с FULLTEXT?

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

Ребят, помогите решить такую проблему, пришлось поддерживать сайт на joomla, и тут понадобилось раскопировать это дело на еще один сайт с другим содержимым. Т.к. все содержимое содержится в БД как я понял, я написал такую тему

`UPDATE d1fsk_content SET fulltext=REPLACE(fulltext, 'Ногинск', 'Люберцы');`

На все столбцы с наименованиями "introtext" допустим, работает, а вот fulltext, это зарезервированное слово и оно не работает выдает ошибку синтаксиса, с этим возможно как-нибудь бороться или придется все руками менять?

Comment: Читайте http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Legal_names.html

Comment: > Т.к. все содержимое содержится в БД как я понял ":  а где ещё должно быть ? > раскопировать это дело на еще один сайт с другим содержимым": что вы хотите скопировать на другой сайт, всю базу или только контент ? вам лучше описать изначально что вы хотите сделать, может другое решение получите, что и как

Comment: В общем, нужно в БД поменять все слова "Ногинск", на слова "Люберцы".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если вопрос в зарезервированных слова, т.е. совпадение имени столбца с зарезервированным словом, то поставьте это слово в обратные одинарные кавычки

`fulltext`

в латинской раскладке клавиша слева от клавиши 1.

Comment: А как клавиша слева от 1 называется?

Comment: @Visman, не понял вопроса. вы имеете ввиду клавишу тильды или символ обратный апостроф? и вообще к чему этот вопрос?)

Comment: Да просто стало интересно почему вы ее не тильда/апостроф назвали.

Comment: @Visman, чтобы не отвечать на вопрос что такое тильда и где находится обратный апостроф, но не прокатило))

Comment: Надо было комбинировать оба варианта, что бы точно вопросов не было)